# House computer with AI takes over home, tries to procreate with woman

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror, artificial-intelligence

A malevolent computer with AI takes over a woman's house with the intent of hybrid computer/human procreation. The evil computer seals off the house with the woman in it and keeps her prisoner while it prepares. I read the tale sometime in the late 80's or the early 90's. It was one of many of my missing books that got yardsaled by my in-laws when I wasn't looking. It may also have been made into a movie, but I didn't see the film.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This sounds like [Demon Seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Seed_%28novel%29), a novel by Dean Koontz made into a movie of the same name.